# Mount but exclude one subfolder?

Tags: linux, mount, nas, symbolic-link, unmount

I have a Synology NAS in which I use the following command at NAS startup to create a symlink, which works fine:

`mount --bind "/volume1/SourceFolder" "/volume1/SymlinkFolder"`

Now I have a new requirement, which is that inside `SourceFolder`, there's a folder several levels down called `FolderToBeHiddenInSymlink` which needs to be excluded from the symlink folder. In order to do this, I thought the `--make-unbindable` option might work, which might prevent this folder showing up in `SymlinkFolder` when the above command is run, but it doesn't work. If I execute this:

`mount --make-unbindable "/volume1/SourceFolder/blah/blah/blah/FolderToBeHiddenInSymlink"`

I get this error:

`mount: /volume1/SourceFolder/blah/blah/blah/FolderToBeHiddenInSymlink: not mount point or bad option.`

Anyone know what's wrong ?

Is there any other way of excluding a subfolder when creating a symlink using `mount` command ?

Comment: `mount` does not create a symlink. Bind mount is not a symlink. I think I understand what you want to do and IMO it makes sense. My point is your *terminology* is wrong.